# Quota limit for doGet()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a custom function with some doGet() calls and I am also using SpreadsheetApp to access my sheet. I have read about the UrlFetch() limit of 20,000 call/day and it is understandable. But I am confused about two things on quota for app script:
 - Is there any limitation to make call to doGet and spreadsheetapp?
 - If yes, then for ex. if I have same such 5 sheets, then the limit will be per each sheet or for all 5 sheets in total?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last month, Google removed all limits on the quota of total data received by UrlFetch per day per user. If you have a consumer Gmail account, you can make up to 20000 calls per day.

However, you still have a restriction around the total time that your script can run per day. It is 90 minutes for consumer Gmail accounts.

See [Quota Limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) for UrlFetch and Total script time.

Comment: So, I do not have any limit for doGet()?

Comment: And is this 20,000 calls per day for each script or all script in my account?

Comment: @amit-agarwal Do you have a link to where it says Google removed those limits? I cannot find anything.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I found it in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#:~:text=these%20restrictions%20do%20not%20apply%20to%20doget(e)%20or%20dopost(e).), under Restrictions. 

I tried to edit the answer, but it seems the edit queue is full :(