# How do Google Apps Script quotas work for doGet and doPost functions in web apps?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, quota

I've read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas and understand what the quotas are and how they work.

What I can't figure out is how the quotas apply to web apps, specifically with the `doGet` and `doPost` functions?

For example:

- Say a web app serves static HTML content via `doGet` -- is `Script runtime` the only quota that would apply?
- Say a web app services dynamic HTML content via `doGet` that pulls and displays data from a Sheet -- which quotas apply?
- What if the web app also accepts form submissions using `doPost` -- then what?

I understand the quotas are applied to the user how owns the web app. I just can't figure out which quotas apply for the web content side of things. Obviously `Script runtime` applies but what else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)(consumer edition) apply:

- Script runtime 6min/execution
- <strike>Trigger total runtime: 90min/day</strike> These seem  to be excluded [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)
- Simultaneous execution: 30

`UrlFetch` quotas (like 50MB/Post size) may also apply to `doPost()`.

Note however that these quotas typically don't apply to you, but to the user, if script is set to execute as "User accessing the webapp". Therefore, a single user can't simultaneously execute script 30 times in a short time(if published to execute as "User accessing the web-app")

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51394074/quota-limit-for-doget):

Google removed all limits on the quota of total data received by `UrlFetch` per day per user. If you have a consumer Gmail account, you can make up to 20000 calls per day. You still have a restriction around the total time that your script can run per day. It is 90 minutes for consumer Gmail accounts.

You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the runtime of scripts called via doGet and doPost does not affect the overall daily runtime limit. However, the execution time for these scripts is still 6 minutes, regardless of the type of Google account being used (consumer or workplace).